# How to set attributes of a div tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

I am having a `div` and using javascript to set attribute for it with the below code

**Javascript**

```
var m = document.getElementById('d1');
m.setAttribute("height","50%");
```

but it throws an error as *`setAttribute()` property cannot be set to the null reference.*

**My HTML Code**

```
<div id="d1" style:"background-color:blue;">
```

Comment: this snipped works. may be an error in the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML markup is wrong it should be  `<div id="d1" style="background-color:blue;">`

syntax for setAttribute

```
element.setAttribute(name, value);
```

[check attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

so, the javascript code should be

```
var m=document.getElementById('d1');
m.setAttribute("style","height:50%");
```

*because height can be directly applied to the following elements `<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>`*

**Live Example**
http://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/bicCL(in example height set to `50px` In your case you can use `%`

Answer (score 1):

Better use `style` instead of `setAttribute`

```
m.style.height = "50%";
```

It will be:

```
<div style="height: 50%;"></div>
```

But your code is valid and it ouputs:

```
<div height="50%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m.setAttribute("style", "height: 50%");
```